# Running GNU Radio in multiple OS's

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am trying to understand (from a python noob perspective) how could I set GNU Radio for multiple OS's/machines usage. Ideally I'd use GRC only on my Ubuntu machine, but run .py from both my windows machine and my raspberry pi. I've seen this thread that implies that using venv is the best alternative (which I'd love), but when I used GNU Radio back in 2018 it seemed that pybombs was the best alternative and usage in MacOS or windows was rather bad.

Is there a good way to handle multiple OS's usage? I want to be sure before installing the required packages and asking the other guys who'll help me with the project to do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A good question should be focused on a _specific problem you already encountered_. Asking folks what problems you might hit makes a question broader than is a good fit for our format: We want each question to be able to have (at least in theory) a canonically-correct answer; and the set of problems one could run into is at least theoretically unbounded.

Comment: BTW, if your hardware is overpowered enough, one approach to consider is virtualization. If everyone is running off the same VM image, portability issues are nicely mooted (though granted, one would want particularly fast USB passthrough performance -- or maybe even PCI passthrough of the whole interface, depending on exactly what your radio hardware is and what throughput you need).

Answer (score 0):

First, please correct me if I am wrong. I am working with @Foxtrot813 on this project and based on @CharlesDuffy comments I've search a bit. So our question was how to properly setup GNU Radio for a project that both of us are going to work on without breaking our PCs. I have used GNU Radio in the past, and I've broken my python and made some very questionable things. So we thought it'd be best to ask properly and do proper research on the topic.

So the ideal way to proceed from our research (answering the question above), seems to be to create a initial [virtual disk](https://superuser.com/questions/235376/how-to-share-a-virtualbox-image) to have exactly the "same" machine with the same GNU Radio installation. Then we can GRC use to generate a `python` code for our `flowgraph`.

For this, we'd then find out the requirements necessary to run under a `venv` and create our `requirements.txt`  to run our program.

I know this is somewhat stupid, but since we asked we might as well answer our question just in case someone also has this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Install it on your Ubuntu machine. Open a remote shell into that machine from the other 2 machines to run the command line python programs. It's hard enough to get everything working on 1 machine, never mind 3, never mind moving all the hardware around risking damage from static and accidents.

A VM is also an option, but you still have to move hardware around, and depending on what you're doing a VM might be too slow, and that's not an option on a RPi.